# HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream: SSL error connection reset

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, xwpf

My java code tries to fetch a document from it's server. Both the code as the document are on a Tomcat server in the same domain. https://domain/webapp/static/document.

When I run this piece of code:

```
try (InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(stream));) {
    
} catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I receive this exception:

> 

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:135)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1143)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1054)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:394)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
    at cob.securitymanager.CustomerBean.createCustomerReadyDocFromTemplate(CustomerBean.java:1894)
    at cob.securitymanager.CustomerBean.downloadFile(CustomerBean.java:1850)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 48 more
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:355)
```

I'm really not an SSL expert.

Comment: Were you able to fix it?